# Layered Navigation On product Page Not Working because of URL

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation, product-urls

i'm using layered navigation in product view page.

On click on any filter, it's simply appending those filter at the end of current url

Example,

This is my current product page url,

```
http://host.com/mento17/index.php/category/product1.html
```

On same product page if i filter by price, i'm redirecing to

```
http://host.com/mento17/lovablenew/index.php/category/product1.html&price=100-500
```

I should go to category listing page,

http://host.com/mento17/index.php/category.html&price=100-500

`getUrl()` is the function which is generating url from `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php`

It's mentioned like below,

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        $query = array(
            $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
            Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
        );
        return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
    }
```

Above function simply appending filter at the end of current url. This works fine in category page but not in product page.

Is there any way to make it work in product page by altering url ?

Comment: Why would you need the layered nav in the product view page? It is not supposed to work like that.

Comment: @Marius yes I know Buddy. But my client badly needs it. He wish to give flexibility to end users who can able to filter products even they are in product page too.

Comment: So why you don't want to rewrite this method and determine current category instead of using just current url?

Answer (score 1):

The question already contains half of the answer.

Rewrite the mentioned class `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php` and determine if we at the product page.  For example like `if(Mage::registry('current_product'))`
then get the first category of the current product and its URL as a base.